# How to update records of two tables through trigger?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update

I have two tables as `employee` and `employee_backup` whenever i update employee table the trigger must update employee_backup table also :
this is the piece of code i was trying to achieve specified goal:

```
 create trigger update_both on employee after update
    As
    Begin
    
        declare @EID varchar(10), 
                @Name varchar(20),
                @age int, 
                @salaray int, 
                @city varchar(20)

        select * from inserted 
    
        update employee_backup 
        set @eid=eid, @name=name, @age=age, @salaray=salaray, @city=city 
        where @eid=eid and @name=name and @age=age

    end
```

before this is able to update employee id and employee backup id but now it is messing up ..
your suggestions matter alot :)

Comment: seriously??? can i ask for the reason behind down vote??

Comment: As already indicated, your code has major problems. But this question is off-topic for dba and more properly belongs on SO. And the comments about "EID is primary key" and "what if no primary key" suggests a level of confusion that should be addressed first. I must question the presence of a table that contains duplicate information for no obvious purpose. Perhaps what you desire is a history table that shows changes over time? That is much different from what you have posted.

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger doesn't update anything, you should join `employee_backup` and `inserted` tables and update affected rows only.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updEmployeeBackup ON employee AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE eb
    SET    name = i.name, age = i.age, salary = i.salary, city = i.city
    FROM   employee_backup eb
    JOIN   inserted i
           ON eb.eid;
END
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110742/discussion-between-ashiq-pervez-and-mcnets).